# How to terminate .NET application on a specific exception - possibly without stack unwinding?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, c++-cli, corrupted-state-exception

I have a .NET application (service) that consists of C# and C++ code.

"Crashes" (i.e. `System.AccessViolationException` and other [Corrupted State Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#Four)) in the C++ Code will be ("non-") handled correctly, they will directly lead to my `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` handler (which logs) and then the application will terminate, writing a WER dump file if so configured (which it is).

For this application, I have determined that `System.NullReferenceException` is always a bug, *especially* since some C++/CLI Access Violation bugs will report this one instead of an AV.

Is there any way to make .NET *not* catch a `NullReferenceException` on an exception boundary (my `OnTimer` callback in this case) but instead directly terminate the app, *without* unwinding the stack, basically "jumping" directly to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`?

Comment: Anybody that catches NRE or AVE usually does so because the C++ programmer is not returning the phone call.  Making his life more miserable is not productive.  You help him by making your code exception-safe with __try/__except, not by removing the options to work around the problem.

Comment: @Hans - what are you talking about? These NRE and AVE are caused by bugs. Bugs Happen. To be able to track down and fix these bugs, I want to avoid catching these exceptions, but get a decent dump file. And what has exception-safe code to do with `__try`/`__catch`? Are you actually suggesting to swallow AVE at the C++ boundary??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `FirstChanceException` is actually a "simple" global exception filter got me on the track (it remains to be seen whether it's the "right" track):

*We already have exception filters in CLI*.

If one has the luxury of working in C# 6, it's as simple as:

```
        try
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("No, Really");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) when (FilterExType(ex))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"2: Caught 'any' exception: {ex}");
        }

    static bool FilterExType(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is NullReferenceException)
        {
            Environment.FailFast("BOOM from C#!", ex);
        }
        // always handle if we return
        return true;
    }
```

And for those of us (like me) stuck on earlier versions, we can route the filtering through VB.NET via a delegate / lambda:

```
        try {
            VbFilterLib.FilteredRunner.RunFiltered(() =>
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Via VB.NET");
            });
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1: Caught 'any' exception: {0}", ex");
        }
```

with VB as such (bear with me, VB.NET is *far* from a language I'm fluent in):

```
Public Class FilteredRunner
    Delegate Sub VoidCode()

    Private Shared Function FilterAction(x As Exception) As Boolean
        If TypeOf x Is NullReferenceException Then
            Environment.FailFast("Abort program! Investigate Bug via crash dump!", x)
        End If
        ' Never handle here:'
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub RunFiltered(code As VoidCode)
        Try
            code.Invoke()
        Catch ex As Exception When FilterAction(ex)
            Throw New InvalidProgramException("Unreachable!", ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Obviously, to make it work you need some more configuration rigging, but that seems to be exactly what I want. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
```

and then

```
static void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception is NullReferenceException)
    {
        Environment.FailFast("FailFast", e.Exception);
    }
}
```

The [`Environment.FailFast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms131100.aspx):

> Immediately terminates a process after writing a message to the Windows Application event log, and then includes the message in error reporting to Microsoft.

and

> This method terminates a process without running any active try/finally blocks or finalizers.

Clearly in the `CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException` you could duplicate the logging code you probably have in your `UnhandledException` (or have a common method that is called by both)

Comment: Excellent. This would certainly be something ... except ... is it advisable to use `FirstChanceException` event wholesale in a released app? (I'm not worried too much about performance in this case, rather some unpleasant side effects?) Just adding an exception filter at a specific excpetion boundary would n my case be rather cleaner.